# Keyboard flashes when navigating in Shell flyouts

Tags: xamarin.forms

My Xamarin.Forms app is using [Shell flyouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout) for navigation. When I navigate the app on iOS, I notice a strange behaviour. Reproduction steps:

1. Go to a page that has an `Entry` in it
2. Type anything into the `Entry`
3. Go to another page
4. Return to the same page you typed something into the `Entry`

The keyboard then pops up and then disappears right after. I can see the cursor in the `Entry` appear then disappear too. I removed a lot of my code to try to find the problem, but I can not find it. My code:

AppShell.xaml:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
   Title="MyApp"
   x:Name="shellAppShell"
   x:Class="MyApp.AppShell">

<FlyoutItem x:Name="flyoutItemMainPage" Title="Home" Icon="icon_about.png">
    <ShellContent x:Name="shellContentMainPage" Route="MainPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem x:Name="flyoutItemAPage" Title="A Page" Icon="Pagea.png">
    <ShellContent x:Name="shellContentPageA" Route="PageA" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PageA}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<!-- More flyouts... -->

</Shell>
```

PageA.xaml:

```
<ContentPage  
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Name="PageA"
         x:Class="MyApp.Views.PageA">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
        <Entry />
        <Button Text="back" Clicked="OnBackClicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

PageA.xaml.cs

```
public partial class PageA : ContentPage
{
    public PageA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void OnBackClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Shell.Current.CurrentItem = AppShellGlobal.ShellContentMainPage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my testing, this situation only occurs in iOS.

There is a simpler solution, you can rewrite the ContentPage and end the editing state of the page when the page loads.

First, create the MyPageRenderer class in your project's **xxx.iOS** directory.

Here is the internal code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
namespace App15.iOS
{
    public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            View.EndEditing(true);//Solved the problem with this line of code
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
        }   
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can this instead be solved by `EndEditing` when the view is disappearing? That way when the page opens again, there is no chance that it will think it is still editing, so the keyboard can't appear for a moment. If this is possible, and safe, I feel that it would be more certain to work on all iOS versions and devices. Just a thought.

Comment: It just changes the edit state of the page. And this problem only occurs in iOS, so I think overriding ContentPage is the easiest way.

Comment: `View` does not have a method `EndEditing`. It is a `UIView` but the method is not there for me.

Comment: Did you add the location correctly? The MyPageRenderer class needs to be created in the ios folder inside your project.

Comment: For the use of custom renderer, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage

Comment: I have added a screenshot for your reference.

Comment: I had to add `using UIKit`. It works now.